# How to programatically prove this code has a race condition?

Tags: go, race-condition, httpserver

I'm told this code has a race condition by design, though try as I may, I'm unable to prove it does.

```
func (h *handler) loggingMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        h.Log = log.WithFields(log.Fields{
            "method":     r.Method,
            "requestURI": r.RequestURI,
        })
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

I tried `go build -race`, then running the binary: `PORT=3000 ./main` & load creators like `hey -n 10000 -c 200 http://localhost:3000`.

Rest of the code here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaihendry/context-youtube/master/5/main.go

Or

```
type handler struct{ Log *log.Entry }

func New() (h *handler) { return &handler{Log: log.WithFields(log.Fields{"test": "FAIL"})} }

func (h *handler) index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    h.Log.Info("index")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello")
}

func (h *handler) about(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    h.Log.Info("about")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "about")
}

func main() {
    h := New()
    app := mux.NewRouter()
    app.HandleFunc("/", h.index)
    app.HandleFunc("/about", h.about)
    app.Use(h.loggingMiddleware)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), app); err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Fatal("error listening")
    }
}
```

If I can't prove it has a race condition, can I assume setting `h.Log` is safe?

Comment: You have a single `handler` instance `h`, which is getting the same `Log` field re-assigned on every request. Getting a race from that was pretty simple by making concurrent requests.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know how to programmatically confirm this, without reasoning so much. Like a lint checker.

Comment: The go race detector will catch this, if you attempt concurrent writes. If your tests don't exercise this code in the right way, you may never detect it, though.

Comment: Though I am using `hey` in a concurrent manner iiuc. So how else can I test ... in the right way?

Comment: Programmatically detecting race conditions is akin to solving the halting problem, there's no way to statically guarantee a particular state can be reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a programmatic way, for which you have to do 2 things:

- reproduce the racy condition
- and use the `-race` option when launching the `go` tool

Best is if you write a unit test for it, so the test is also reproducible, and run / checked automatically on each build / deploy.

Ok, so how to reproduce it?

Simply write a test which launches 2 goroutines, one which calls the `index` handler, and one which calls the `about` handler, deliberately without synchronization, this is what triggers the race detector.

Use the [`net/http/httptest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/) package to easily test handlers. [`httptest.NewServer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewServer) hands you a ready server, "armed" with the handler you pass to it.

Here's a simple test example that will trigger the race condition. Put it in a file named `main_test.go`, next to your `main.go` file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "sync"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func TestRace(t *testing.T) {
    h := New()
    app := mux.NewRouter()
    app.HandleFunc("/", h.index)
    app.HandleFunc("/about", h.about)
    app.Use(h.loggingMiddleware)

    server := httptest.NewServer(app)
    defer server.Close()

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for _, path := range []string{"/", "/about"} {
        path := path
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, server.URL+path, nil)
            fmt.Println(server.URL + path)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            defer res.Body.Close()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

You have to run it with

```
go test -race
```

And an example output will be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:33007/
http://127.0.0.1:33007/about
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c000098030 by goroutine 17:
  play.(*handler).loggingMiddleware.func1()
      /home/icza/tmp/gows/src/play/main.go:16 +0x1ce
  net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1964 +0x51
  github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP()
      /home/icza/tmp/gows/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:212 +0x12e
  net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2741 +0xc4
  net/http.(*conn).serve()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1847 +0x80a

Previous write at 0x00c000098030 by goroutine 16:
  play.(*handler).loggingMiddleware.func1()
      /home/icza/tmp/gows/src/play/main.go:16 +0x1ce
  net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1964 +0x51
  github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP()
      /home/icza/tmp/gows/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:212 +0x12e
  net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2741 +0xc4
  net/http.(*conn).serve()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1847 +0x80a

Goroutine 17 (running) created at:
  net/http.(*Server).Serve()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2851 +0x4c5
  net/http/httptest.(*Server).goServe.func1()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/httptest/server.go:280 +0xac

Goroutine 16 (running) created at:
  net/http.(*Server).Serve()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2851 +0x4c5
  net/http/httptest.(*Server).goServe.func1()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/httptest/server.go:280 +0xac
==================
2019/01/06 14:58:50  info index                     method=GET requestURI=/
2019/01/06 14:58:50  info about                     method=GET requestURI=/about
--- FAIL: TestRace (0.00s)
    testing.go:771: race detected during execution of test
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    play    0.011s
```

The test fails, showing that there are data races.

**Notes:**

The synchronization with the `sync.WaitGroup` is to wait for the 2 launched goroutines, it is not to synchronize access to the handler's logger (which causes the data race). This is so if you fix the data race, the test will run and end properly (waiting for the 2 launched test-goroutines to complete).

Comment: Wow, amazing thank you. I've added your answer to https://github.com/kaihendry/context-youtube

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you receive two inbound connections at almost the same time that hit the same handler.  The first connection starts running:

```
h.Log = log.WithFields(log.Fields{
    "method":     rFirst.Method,
    "requestURI": rFirst.RequestURI,
})
```

But wait!  A second connection shows up!  Maybe the runtime wants to suspend this goroutine and launch the second connection.  Then...

```
h.Log = log.WithFields(log.Fields{
    "method":     rSecond.Method,
    "requestURI": rSecond.RequestURI,
})
next.ServeHTTP(wSecond, rSecond)
```

Phew...that's done with.  Let's go back to our first goroutine.

```
// What's in h.Log now, with this sequence of events?
next.ServeHTTP(wFirst, rFirst)
```

> Or...

Your second set of examples don't change the value of `h.Log`, but do call methods on it.  This may or may not be safe in the most general case.  The [documentation for `log.Logger`](https://godoc.org/log#Logger) contains the magic phrase: "A Logger can be used simultaneously from multiple goroutines".  (If you've actually imported `"github.com/sirupsen/logrus"` as `log`, [that has a similar statement in its documentation](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus#thread-safety).)

> can I assume setting h.Log is safe?

Without a `sync.Mutex` or something similar protecting it, not really.  You definitely do not have a guarantee that, if you set it on line 1, it will have the same value on line 2 if some other goroutine might be changing it.  [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) has a more precise definition of what side effects are guaranteed to be visible when.

Comment: So there is no programmatic way to determine it has a race condition?